# Passing Variable from one script to another

Tags: debian, shell-script, variable

How can I pass a variable between scripts?

Example: I have two test scripts:

```
-- test2.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "this is test2.sh"
echo "varname is $varname"
echo end

-- tes1.sh
#!/bin/bash 
varname="123456"
ssh user@111.222.333.444 
"bash" < varname=$varname test2.sh
```

The idea is that I run `test1.sh` which connects to a remote server, and executes `test2.sh`. But all I am getting is `varName is 123456: No such file or directory`

Comment: well spotted. .  . that was a typo

Comment: Do you have a copy of `test2.sh` locally?

Comment: `test1.sh` and `test2.sh` exist only on the main server, However, `test2.sh`  contains code that connects to a database and runs some queries. The `varname` variable(s) will contain database connection details amongst others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running into an "order of operations" type problem I think.  The `<` is processed before the commands are execute, so you're running something similar (though not identical to)

```
varname=$varname test2.sh | ssh user@111.222.333.444 bash
```

which runs the `test2.sh` locally, then sends that output to `bash` on the remote server.  That's why you see the output of `test2.sh` but then get an error when it tries to execute that output as a command.

If you're running a script that's executable you don't really need the `bash` there though, so you could just do

```
ssh user@111.222.333.444 "varname=$varname ./test2.sh"
```

assuming `test2.sh` is available on the remote server.

If you don't have `test2.sh` on the remote server and still want to execute it there you could do it like so:

```
ssh user@111.222.333.444 varname="$varname" bash < test2.sh
```

which will redirect the script source but do the variable processing in the context of the `bash` executable

Comment: that's closer cheers, but not quite. I am just getting `varname is ` with no numbers.

Comment: Hmm, and you're sure you have the same capitalization on `varname` still, right?  Because when I test this execution with a simple script I'm getting the value printed on the other side

Comment: it is. I added `echo test1 varname is $varname` to test1.sh just to make sure it was being set properly, and that works fine. It just doesn't copy across.

Comment: Ah ha, in test2.sh I still had `varname is $1` instead of `varname is $varname`. It now works. Cheers for your help,

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just pass it as an argument.  ie.

test2.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "this is test2.sh"
echo "varName is $1"
echo end
```

test1.sh

```
#!/bin/bash 
varName="123456"
scp test2.sh user@111.222.333.444:/tmp/
ssh user@111.222.333.444 "/tmp/test2.sh $varName"
ssh user@111.222.333.444 "rm -f /tmp/test2.sh"
```

Comment: cheers, by that gives me `bash: test2.sh: command not found`

Comment: Is `test2.sh` located on the local machine or the remote one?

Comment: the local machine (same place as test1.sh)

Comment: If you want to run `test2.sh` on the remote machine it should be located there.

Comment: The problem is that there is apx 70 machines to run it on, and as the script is the same for all of them I don't want to try and maintain 70 copies of it.

Comment: See my edited `test1.sh`

Answer (score 0):

To define a process's environment on the command-line you need to order your definitions *before* the command:

```
varname=$varname bash < $varname test1.sh
```

It also seems unlikely to me that you really want to open a file named...

```
varname=${expansion_of_varname}
```

though that appears to be what you are trying to do. I expect that will cause issues as well. If you want *every* variable assignment to affect the environment of all of the shell's children, then you can do:

```
set -a
```

...first. *(though even then `x=; <${x:=file} sh -c 'echo "$x"'` still doesn't appear to work without an intervening semicolon)*.