# Running remote command with ssh getting "bash: /dev/fd/63: No such file or directory"

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, file-descriptors, process-substitution

I have `/root/test.sh` on a remote server, which has the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash
date
```

On the remote server, I get the following output:

```
# ./test.sh
Fri Dec 18 07:41:10 EST 2015

# bash <(cat /root/test.sh)
Fri Dec 18 07:41:23 EST 2015
```

However, if I try to run the same commands from my local machine, I get the following result:

```
$ ssh root@remote_server /root/test.sh
Fri Dec 18 07:44:32 EST 2015

$ ssh root@remote_server bash <(cat /root/test.sh)
cat: /root/test.sh: No such file or directory
bash: /dev/fd/63: No such file or directory
```

So what's the problem of the last run? You might find it weird to run a script like this `bash <(cat /root/test.sh)`. The reason I did it is because it is a simplified version of my real situation. My real code is to download a Bash script from the Internet and run it locally. I have a lot of machines to run, with different parameters, so I'm trying to run them from my local computer.

Comment: Try `ssh root@remote_server /bin/cat test.sh `, for the simplified version.

Comment: This is actually pretty similar to http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/248345/passing-variable-from-one-script-to-another and is more-or-less suffering from the same problem I think.  You don't really need process substitution as you might see from the other question

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't pass file descriptors like this over `ssh`. `<(...)` construction creates virtual files on your system and it does not have a meaning when executing on remote system.

If you really want to use it, put it into the quotes, which will evaluate on the remote system, if you have bash there

```
ssh root@remote_host "bash <( cat /root/test.sh )"
```

Answer (score 4):

My suggestion is to do a script on the remote host (`/root/test.sh`) make it executable (`chmod u+x /root/test.sh`) and run in the following way

```
ssh root@remote_server /bin/bash -c  /root/test.sh
```

About 
`/bin/bash: /dev/fd/63: No such file or directory`
You can read  reasons on this answer <sup>[[1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156088/66388)]</sup>.

Note:
Take the good habit to use the full path (`/bin/bash`) instead of only the command name (`bash`) to avoid unneeded security risks <sup>[[2](http://techterms.com/definition/trojanhorse)]</sup>.

---

Another way should be

```
ssh root@remote_server << EOF
cat  /root/test.sh
# whatever else
EOF
```

It will execute each line until the second EOF... you can do your variants about it...

Answer (score 1):

I recently faced the same problem, but then I realized that it only happens if you run with **sudo/root** user.

If I run:

```
sudo bash <(echo "It worked")
```

I get:

```
bash: /dev/fd/63: No such file or directory
```

But if I run:

```
bash <(echo "It worked")
```

It works just fine.

Comment: Issue is related to `ssh` not to `sudo`

Comment: Well, I tried the same command locally with sudo (without ssh) and remotely with ssh (with and without root user) and the problem was always when running with sudo, regardless of ssh.